# Is a Zav allowed to have relations with his wife?

Tags: halacha, sexuality, zav-zava

Would a Zav be allowed to have relations with his wife while she is Tahor? I can't think of any source to forbid it.

Comment: Why might you think it would be prohibited, that you choose to ask, if you can't think of any source to forbid it? Surely there are many things that you can't think of sources forbidding which you haven't chosen to ask about. Why choose this one?

Comment: Because Zavah is so Assur and it feels  like they should be similar.

Comment: @Eliyahu Additional information that you provide in response to comments should be  edited into the post itself.

Answer (score 11):

Yep. See [Tosefta Zavim 1:9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_21497_187.pdf), זב מותר בתשמיש המטה בימי גמרו, and Chasdei David there. Also [Yerushalmi Shabbos 1:3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_14141_21.pdf), לא יאכל הזב עם הזבה הא זב עם מצורעת מותר, and Pnei Moshe there.